# XML document error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

This is the code for uploading a XML document to validate. 
This code gives some exception problem at the line containing the code
`xmlDoc.Load(reader);`.

The particular exception message is "The Exception was unhandled by the user code".

```
   private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("mycompany.xml"));

       reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
       XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
       //Load the file into the XmlDocument
       xmlDoc.Load(reader);
       //Close off the connection to the file.
       reader.Close();
       //Add and item representing the document to the listbox
       lbNodes.Items.Add("XML Document");
       //Find the root nede, and add it togather with its childeren
       XmlNode xnod = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
       AddWithChildren(xnod,1);
   }
```

Comment: We'll have to see the full details of the exception, as well as the XML. I would guess you have malformed XML in `mycompany.xml`.

Comment: This code should work fine without any problem. So i am 100 % sure it is a problem with resolving the path to your XML file/ the XML is not valid.